# Which way to go after C++?

Tags: 3d

I have 2 years learning C++ and created an RPG text-based game lately.
Everything I have done so far was about pure C++ and the console,
with the exception of a game in Allegro 5.
Now I want to start learning 3D directly, since 2D programming is
a cropped down version of it and I am better in 3D than 2D in maths.
I was watching Irrlicht and it seems very good.
So basically choices are:
Learn more C++ || Jump into 2D again || Go with 3D

Which one is really worth it? I personally think going with 
Irrlicht is the best option which is a graphics engine 
and from the demos it could do everything I think of.

Comment: "what should I learn next" is explicitly off topic.  See the [faq].  In short, this kind of question is truly unanswerable in a Q&A sense.

Comment: First choose a framework, second find a beginner tutorial, third code a small game that is within your skills.

Comment: i would suggest you go with directX if youre gonna do 3D C++, but i dont suggest making 3D games without making a 2D game in that language also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise against "Learn more C++" in favour of creating something because you'll learn more with hands-on experience. I'd recommend to consider getting some experience with mobile app development by making a game. There are some C++ SDKs that allow you to build for iOS and Android(I can think of [MarmaladeSDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmaladesdk)(non-free)).

3D has a much higher payoff, but it is also more of a challenge. There is only so much you can learn from 2D.
For engines/frameworks for 3D that you could choose from:

- [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org)
- [Pand3D](http://www.panda3d.org/)
- [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/)
- [Spring(RTS) engine](http://springrts.com/)
- [Crystal Space](http://www.crystalspace3d.org)
- etc etc

You could also check out [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) or [Unreal Development Kit](http://udk.com/)

If you go with Irrlicht you'll also need to pick a sound library you can find [here](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.SoundLibraries). You could check out some open-source games and see how they perform with their engines or get some ideas on how they use it. [Minetest](http://minetest.net/) uses Irrlicht.

You can't really go wrong with any of these libraries, although I would research their portability if you're interested in developing for mobile/other platforms.